# How to fix UILabel alignment in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios

I put a custom `UILabel` in my `UINavigation` bar like this:

```
UILabel *navTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
navTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navTitle.text = @"TEST";
navTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamNarrowBook-Regular" size:28];
navTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitle;
```

But when it shows up on the emulator, its aligned too high:

[image]

I have had no luck with adjusting the frame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put label inside another view, and insert this another one as titleView. That will allow some kind of flexibility.

You can also try to adjust position of the frame:

```
UILabel *navTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, >>>10<<<, 200, 44)];
```

But remember, that NavigationBar has different height in landscape mode, so you have to use autoresizingMask accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the frame of self.nagivationItem.titleView and push it down?

```
CGRect initialFrame = self.navigationItem.titleView;
self.navigationItem.titleView = CGRectMake(initialFrame.origin.x, initialFrame.origin.y+10, initialFrame.size.width, initialFrame.size.height);
```

Another thing to check, make sure your UINavigationBar is actually 44px tall, if your UILabel is the same height then I believe default behavior is to center vertically which would land it in the correct position.

Comment: I fixed some assumed typos and tried it:  CGRect initialFrame = self.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
    self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = CGRectMake(initialFrame.origin.x, initialFrame.origin.y+10, initialFrame.size.width, initialFrame.size.height);   No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that increasing the height of the UILAbel doesn't work.
Or the Y position.
And I take it you tried adjusting the frame after it's created, e.g. other than in the initWithFrame.

Maybe try using an image instead? Well it's an idea ;)